# python randomly shuffled multiple choice questionaire

Tags: python, subclass

I'm making a subclass for multiple choice questions under a superclass of trivia questions for my Python university course.  The multiple choice aspect works, but I want to shuffle the order of the answers for extra credit.

Some of my code:

```
class ChoiceQuestion(Question) :
def __init__(self) :
  super().__init__()
  self._choices = []

def addChoice(self, choice, correct) :
  self._choices.append(choice)
  if correct :
     # Convert len(choices) to string.
     choiceString = str(len(self._choices))
     self.setAnswer(choiceString)

# Override Question.display().
def display(self) :
  # Display the question text.
  super().display()

  # Display the answer choices.
  for i in range(len(self._choices)) :
     choiceNumber = i + 1
     print("%d: %s" % (choiceNumber, self._choices[i]))
```

The question choices are added in a seperate file I have no control over as a test-file. This is run by the professor after turning in whatever variation of the first code.  Here is what he runs it on.  Side note: there are of course import statements in the second file, but I have the other stuff solved and it's very long.  Didn't want to include stuff that has been worked out.

```
print('\n')
mcq = ChoiceQuestion()
mcq.setText("In which country was the inventor of Python born?")
mcq.addChoice("Australia", False)
mcq.addChoice("Canada", False)
mcq.addChoice("Netherlands", True)
mcq.addChoice("United States", False)
for i in range(3) :
    presentQuestion(mcq)

## Presents a question to the user and checks the response.
#  @param q the question
#
def presentQuestion(q) :
   q.display()   # Uses dynamic method lookup.
   response = input("Your answer: ")
   if q.checkAnswer(response):
       print("Correct")
   else:
       print("Incorrect")   # checkAnswer uses dynamic method lookup.

# Start the program.
```

With that said, I need to display the options in a random order, while updating the number value tied to that choice slot. I.e. if Netherlands is randomized into slot 1, typing "1" will print "Correct".  I also have to make sure I don't allow the same option to appear more than once.

How should I go about it?  What are some suggestions? Note: I can only modify the first program

Comment: Look at python built-in module [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things to think about:

1. As kiran.koduru mentioned, look at using the [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for easily shuffling lists.
2. Currently your code stores the correct answer as it is received. This makes it difficult because when the answers are shuffled the stored answer is no longer correct. An alternative is to store `choice` and `correct` together and calculate the correct answer **after** your choices are shuffled.
3. Your code does not know in `addChoice` whether or not there will be more choices added, so shuffling there will result in wasted computation.